# Tracking down an elusive book

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, textbook-recommendation, topological-quantum-field-theory, books

A few weeks ago I had a very engaging talk with a faculty member, where he told me lots of interesting things about quantum algebras, know theory and Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants (this field is not my domain of of expertise).

Among other things he searched on the internet for an introductory book for this field and we browsed through a few ones, until he found one that he mentioned might be interesting to me.

Because I received so much information, I wasn't able to remember the name of that book! I searched in vain for keywords like "quantum groups", "quantum algebras", "TQFT".

I only remember that:

- the book had 2 (or more) Russian authors
- in the first ~100 pages it developed a lot of abstract category-theoretic machinery, before it turned to more concrete things (to the point that said faculty member wondered whether that was actually necessary in order to understand the concrete stuff)
- it had a cover that looked similar to [this](https://books.google.ro/books?id=GPLzBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=quantum%20algebras&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13a6Yq-7jAhVyiIsKHQE_Bew4MhDoAQh1MAg#v=onepage&q=quantum%20algebras&f=false) or like [this](https://books.google.ro/books?id=01xlGB8qVNYC&pg=PA237&dq=quantum%20algebras&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJnejqrO7jAhWm_CoKHRAFAnU4ChDoAQhxMAk#v=onepage&q=quantum%20algebras&f=false) in terms of color and layout
- it came up on the right-hand side of the browser in Google (not Google books) when searching for it, so it must be frequently searched-for book
- It contains some knot theory as well

Could you please help me find that book? I hope all of these contraints will hopefully uniquely identify it.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't ask the faculty member?

Comment: [Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-Manifolds](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/461906) has the right color but only one Russian author, Turaev.

Comment: [Tensor Categories](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z6XLDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Reshetikhin-Turaev&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) seems to roughly match your description, but I suspect it is not unique in that regard.

Comment: As you mention "might be interesting to me" perhaps it would be helpful to know about your area of expertise, background, and interests. In general, Tensor Categories is self contained and would certainly be a good starting point, as would books like Kassel's "Quantum Groups," Turaev's previously mentioned book, Bakalov and Kirilov's "Tensor Categories and Modular Functors," Zhenghan Wang's "Topological Quantum Computing." So much of what would be good and direct answering this question is dependent upon what part of the conversation had you going "Wow! That's cool!"

Comment: @LSpice Yes, there is, but I can't share it here.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke It's not this book unfortunately, I already checked it out. But thank you for the effort.

Comment: @RobinHouston My first gut reaction was "Yes, that is it!!". Then I went through the Contents and now I I'm only "70%" sure it was this book, since I remember that it should have contained something on knots, but this book does'tn really seem to. But maybe I'm not remembering right.

Comment: @MatthewTitsworth By chance I met a string of people recently who all knew a bit about Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants and the other things linked to this circle of ideas. I wanted to get an expert's opinion on this, because I was intrigued by these dialogues (my own background is far removed from these fields). Because I favor texts where a theory is presented with some concrete application in mind, I was directed to this book (among a whole slew of other articles to read, which I thankfully all remembered), where also some applications of the abstract theory were covered.

Comment: @user43263 What are the papers?

Comment: @MatthewTitsworth This one https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3652 and most of the other recommended papers are contained in the references section of the linked paper.

Comment: This is a pretty common starting points for studying quantum groups and their representation categories. Books which I would recommend that focus on this are Kassel (above), Chari and Pressley's "Introduction to Quantum Groups," Frolich and Kerler's "Quantum Groups, Quantum Categories, and Quantum Field Theory," Fuchs' "Symmetry, Lie Algebras, and Representations," Kauffman's "Temperley Lieb Recoupling Theory." Connes' "Noncommutative Geometry" is also good, but different, as is Evans and Kawahigashi's "Quantum Symmetries on Operator Algebras."

Comment: @MatthewTitsworth Thanks you for the recommendations!

Comment: The covers don't match, but could it be [Bakalov and Kirillov, "Lectures on tensor categories and modular functor"](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html)?